# Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7786 ANT build java web-application failing to deploy

Tags: java, ant, wildfly

When-ever I try to deploy the Java web-application it's failing hitting me with a array out of bounds exception. In my project we are using ANT build following is the error on the server.log.

1. Colleagues working on the same code do-not seem to be facing the issue.
2. The project ear is built from two other sub-projects and the jars from those sub-projects are copied into the lib of the final project before building it.

```
2021-03-03 12:44:09,035 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 333) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/promo.mobile": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/promo.mobile": java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7786
                    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:84)
                    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
                    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
                Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7786
                    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
                    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
                    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
                    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:136)
                    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.JarFileScanner.scan(JarFileScanner.java:97)
                    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner$1.f(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:94)
                    at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
                    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:92)
                    at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.servlet.WebAppResourcesScanner.scan(WebAppResourcesScanner.java:79)
                    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
                    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.init(WebAppResourceConfig.java:102)
                    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:89)
                    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.servlet.WebAppResourceConfig.<init>(WebAppResourceConfig.java:74)
                    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.getWebAppResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:668)
                    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:415)
                    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.getDefaultResourceConfig(ServletContainer.java:582)
                    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebServletConfig.getDefaultResourceConfig(WebServletConfig.java:87)
                    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:699)
                    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
                    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:203)
                    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
                    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
                    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
                    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
                    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
                    at io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
                    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:250)
                    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:133)
                    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:565)
                    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:536)
                    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
                    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
                    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
                    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
                    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
                    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
                    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
                    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
                    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:578)
                    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
                    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
                    ... 6 more
                
    2021-03-03 12:44:09,038 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "promo.mobile.ear")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host.\"/promo.mobile\""
=> "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7786
                    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7786"}}
                2021-03-03 12:44:09,058 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "promo.mobile.ear" (runtime-name : "promo.mobile.ear")
                2021-03-03 12:44:09,058 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
                WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/promo.mobile": java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7786
```

Comment: How did you install Jersey?

Comment: Did you find any solution? Because I'm facing same issue now.